# How can I loop this? Mutually exclusive nearest neighbours

Tags: r, loops, nearest-neighbor

I found a function `applynbd` to calculate the nearest distance but I realised the some points from a neighbourhood will appear in other neighbourhoods. I wanted them to be mutually exclusive but the code doesn't seem to be able to do that? So I've decided to code this up but can't seem to be able to loop it...

```
k <- matrix(NA, nrow=375, ncol=5)
count <- 0
```

This computes the distance between the 375 coordinates :

```
l <- gDistance(coord,byid=TRUE)
```

This orders the coordinates from nearest to furthest  :

```
 t <- matrix(order(l[count+1,], decreasing=F))
```

Chooses the five nearest points from first point:

```
k[1,] <- t[1:5,1]
```

This chooses 5 nearest points to 2nd point such that no points are the same as the 5 nearest point for 1st point:

```
t1<- matrix(order(l[count+2,], decreasing=F))
k1 <- matrix(t1 [! t1 %in% k])
k[2,] <- k1[1:5,1]
```

I want to continue this iterative process:

```
  t2<- matrix(order(l[count+3,], decreasing=F))
    k2 <- matrix(t2 [! t2 %in% k])
    k[3,] <- k2[1:5,1]
    t3<- matrix(order(l[count+4,], decreasing=F))
    k3 <- matrix(t3 [! t3 %in% k])
    k[4,] <- k3[1:5,1]
```

...

Comment: Cna you add a `dput` for `coord`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned the packages you are finding these functions in your post.

Comment: The coord is a spatial points data frame using the sp package. I used the function gDistance from rgeos to calculate the distances between each point so it is just a vector.